# Issues with identifiers and templates: my thought process and solution

Tags: c++, templates, types, compiler-errors, linked-list

I had an issue with a school project.  We're learning some data structures concepts, and were given some code defining template classes. The syntax the professor gave was incorrect, and I researched and eventually solved the issue.  I had typed up a question here, as I tried solutions. Eventually I solved the issue and figured I should keep the question and post it, to create a thread where I can show my own thought process, as well as provide a place for others to demonstrate their own techniques and thought processes in regards to template classes.  I'll admit, I'm not sure if there's a place for this kind of stuff on Stack Overflow, but I thought here might be a decent place to put it.

So I have an assignment in which singly-linked lists are used, and we've been provided with code defining 3 classes: `List`, `ListItr`, and `ListNode`.
Each class is a template, allowing for the list to take any class type. The definitions are as follows:
**List**

```
template <class Object> class List
{
public:
    List();
    List(const List * rhs);
    ~List();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    void makeEmpty();
    ListItr<Object> zeroth() const; //errors thrown here
    ListItr<Object> first() const;  //errors thrown here
    void insert(const Object & x, const ListItr <Object> & p); //errors thrown here
    ListItr<Object> find(const Object & x) const; //errors thrown here
    ListItr<Object> findPrevious(const Object & x) const; //errors thrown here
    void remove(const Object & x);
    const List & operator = (const List & rhs);
private:
    ListNode<Object> * header; //errors thrown here
};
```

**ListItr**

```
template <class Object> class ListItr
{
public:
    ListItr() : current(NULL){}
    bool isPastEnd() const
    {return current == NULL;}
    void advance()
    {
        if(!isPastEnd()) current = current->next;
    }
    const Object & retrieve() const
    {
        if(isPastEnd()) throw BadIterator();
        return current->element;
    }
private:
    ListNode <Object> *current; //errors thrown here
    ListItr(ListNode<Object> *theNode) : current(theNode) {} //different error here
    //here it complains that ListItr member function already defined
    friend List<Object>;
};
```

**ListNode**

```
template <class Object> class ListNode
{
    ListNode(const Object & theElement = Object(), ListNode * n = NULL) : element(theElement), next(n)
    {}
    Object element;
    ListNode *next;
    friend List<Object>;
    friend ListItr<Object>;
};
```

To clear up confusion, I cannot use `std::list`, as it uses doubly-linked lists.
I've commented all areas where errors are thrown when I try to compile.  The compiler notes:

```
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed...
C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '>'
```

I've also noted a separate issue, but that is not the big problem I'm having, so it can be ignored for the purposes of this discussion.
The issue is that the compiler won't recognize the classes `List`,`ListItr`, or `ListNode` as types. After some research, I tried these prototypes to resolve the issue, as the way I understood it, there's a syntax error in the method of declaring a template function.  There weren't many examples online that showed comparisons between the correct and incorrect methods, so here are some that I tried:

```
ListItr zeroth() const;

ListItr<class Object> zeroth() const;

ListItr<class> zeroth() const;

ListItr<Object> Object zeroth() const;
```

These are all incorrect, because they focus on `ListItr`, and not the function and its return type itself, and there's just too much going on in each of these prototypes.

The correct syntax simply describes the type, the name of the function, and the input types:

```
Object zeroth() const;
```

You'll notice that each of the templates uses the system of

```
template <class Object> class NAME
```

So, in a function that returns a generic type, the only declaration required is the name of the generic that's being used, in this case `Object`.
In my case, I'm not sure about the reasoning for the use of `const` so much in the code, but that can be ignored to describe a generic syntax for declaring a function of generic return type.
So, to summarize, the correct syntax of declaring a function with generic return type is as follows:

```
template <class Object> class Name
Object function(type1, type2,...);
```

And the correct syntax of defining a function with generic return type is as follows:

```
template <class Object> class Name
template <class Object> Object Name<Object>::function(type1 parameter1, type2 parameter2, ...)
```

If I've missed something, or anything is incorrect here, please comment/answer so I can clear up inconsistencies.

Comment: You'll get better feedback on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  "Have I missed something?" is not the kind of question that StackOverflow answers.

Comment: Thanks, now that I know that exists, I can use that more often!